# Keras official example of LSTM classifier using real values for training target?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, lstm, loss-function

From the official example in Keras docs, the stacked LSTM classifier is trained using `categorical_crossentropy` as a loss function, as expected.  https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/#examples

But the `y_train` values are seeded using `numpy.random.random()` which outputs real numbers, versus `0,1` binary classification ( which is typical )

Are the `y_train` values being promoted to `0,1` values under the hood?

Can you even train this loss function against real values between `0,1` ?

How is `accuracy` then calculated ?

Confusing.. no?

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
import numpy as np

data_dim = 16
timesteps = 8
num_classes = 10

# expected input data shape: (batch_size, timesteps, data_dim)
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True,
               input_shape=(timesteps, data_dim)))  # returns a sequence of vectors of dimension 32
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))  # returns a sequence of vectors of dimension 32
model.add(LSTM(32))  # return a single vector of dimension 32
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Generate dummy training data
x_train = np.random.random((1000, timesteps, data_dim))
y_train = np.random.random((1000, num_classes))

# Generate dummy validation data
x_val = np.random.random((100, timesteps, data_dim))
y_val = np.random.random((100, num_classes))

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=64, epochs=5,
          validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this example, the y_train and y_test are not the one-hot encoding anymore, but the probabilities of each classes. So it is still applicable for cross-entropy. And we can treat the one-hot encoding as the special case of the probabilities vector.

```
y_train[0]
array([0.30172708, 0.69581121, 0.23264601, 0.87881279, 0.46294832,
       0.5876406 , 0.16881395, 0.38856604, 0.00193709, 0.80681196])
```

Comment: There is one short introduction about [cross-entropy](https://rdipietro.github.io/friendly-intro-to-cross-entropy-loss/)